# scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I want to be able to parse strings like the one below with Scala parser combinators.

`aaa22[bbb33[ccc]ddd]eee44[fff]`

Before every open square bracket an integer literal is guaranteed to exist.

The code I have so far:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

trait AST
case class LetterSeq(value: String) extends AST
case class IntLiteral(value: String) extends AST
case class Repeater(count: AST, content: List[AST]) extends AST

class ExprParser extends RegexParsers {
  def intLiteral: Parser[AST] = "[0-9]+".r ^^ IntLiteral
  def letterSeq: Parser[AST] = "[a-f]+".r ^^ LetterSeq
  def term: Parser[AST] = letterSeq | repeater
  def expr: Parser[List[AST]] = rep1(term)
  def repeater: Parser[AST] = intLiteral ~> "[" ~> expr <~ "]" ^^ {
    case intLiteral ~ expr => Repeater(intLiteral, expr)
  }
}
```

The message I get:

```
<console>:25: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : ExprParser.this.~[a,b]
 required: List[AST]
           case intLiteral ~ expr => Repeater(intLiteral, expr)
```

Any ideas?

Later Edit: After making the change suggested by @sepp2k I still get the same error. The change being:

`def repeater: Parser[AST] = intLiteral ~ "[" ~> expr <~ "]" ^^ {`

Comment: I've amended my answer in response to your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you're pattern matching a list against the `~` constructor, which isn't allowed. In order to use `~` in your pattern, you need to have used `~` in the parser.

It looks like in this case the problem is simply that you discarded the value of `intLiteral` using `~>` when you did not mean to. If you use `~` instead of `~>` here and add parentheses<sup>1</sup>, that should fix your problem.

<sup>1</sup> The parentheses are required, so that the following `~>` only throws away the bracket instead of the result of `intLiteral ~ "["`. `intLiteral ~ "[" ~> expr <~ "]"` is parsed as `(intLiteral ~ "[") ~> expr <~ "]"`, which still throws away the `intLiteral`. You want `intLiteral ~ ("[" ~> expr <~ "]")` which only throws away the `[` and `]`.